# Adding a new pot to my guitar

Tags: electric-guitar, maintenance

I am willing to add another tone potentiometer to my guitar and I wanted to know what is the best way to add a hole in the pickguard for the new pot.

Is there a dedicated tool for this task? What is the best and safest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simplest bet is just to use a drill bit suitable for plastics (assuming it is a plastic pick guard)

I would probably use a small bit first, then one with the correct diameter for your pot, or better yet, something like this, which gives you the best of both worlds.

[image]

This is the Armeg WWB10.0T Wood Beaver Drill 10mm